# Java - Trouble uploading file using getPart()

Tags: java, html, servlets, upload

EDIT: I've discovered that my form is not passing any parameters on submit, I'm not sure why that would be.

I have a servlet class:

```
@MultipartConfig
  public class TrainingServlet extends HttpServlet { .. }
```

Inside I have my doPost method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String reqParm = req.getParameter("handler");

    ...

    if ("parsefile".equals(reqParm)) {
        Part part = req.getPart("file");
        new ParseHotelFile().ParseHotelFile(part);      
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/training/uploadhotels.jsp").forward(req,resp);       
    }
}
```

My problem is, whenever the line "Part part = req.getPart("file");" is called, a nullpointerexception is thrown; I can't figure out why. I checked my servlet version and it's 3.0.

Here's my html form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/trainingservlet?handler=parsefile">
<table style="background-color:f0f0f0; padding:8px; border:1px solid #80bfff">
    <tr>
        <td>File to upload: <input style="background-color:#e0e0e0; border:1px solid #a0a0a0" type="file" name="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><br><input type="submit" value="Import"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems to me that your req object is getting unset. Can you show the full function.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The full function is a long series of else-ifs that handle different values for reqParm